# What is best way to implement multi line bread crumb links in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to implement a multiline breadcrumb links for mobile/tablet devices. User will be navigating through multiple folders and if it exceeds the max lines configured of breadcrumb link container I am dropping out links from beginning (trying to show maximum path from current path). Couldn't find a css method for this. Please find an example below with `max line = 2`

```
current path = 
path1 / path2 
/ path3 / path4
/path5
```

exceeds at path5 (went to 3rd line  should update the link to

```
updated path = 
.../ path2 
/ path3 / path4
```

if user navigates back should updates without the ellipse.
I tried  the below methods, didn't work out as expected -

1. css way to clamp to max lines // it didn't work since we need to find how many links to trim
2. Using `white-space: no wrap`  and `text-overflow: ellipse`, I can't use it since it wont allow multiline
3. tried to find maximum number of characters fit in a single line of div using expression - `Width(in pixel) * Font Constant / font Size (in pixels)`

Figured out width and font size dynamically. but couldn't figure out how to get the font constant of an element.
Any help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could use some JS to calculate the height of the container (the element where the path is inside of) and wrap each path in a separate element (<span>path1</span>, ...) and then remove as many <span /> elements from the beginning until the container reaches it maximum height

Comment: For that I need to use pure javascript right ? , any way we can do with the components?

Answer (score 1):

I created a demo component here. Hope it will be helpful.
The strategy I'm using here is:

1. Count lines by dividing the height of the wrapper by the line height
2. Remove items from the beginning until the number of lines is reduced to the maximum allowed

Breadcrumbs.js

```
import { createRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Breadcrumbs.css";

function Breadcrumbs() {

    const wrapper = createRef();
    const ellipsis = createRef();
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [dropped, setDropped] = useState(false);

    const countLines = (element, lineHeight) => {
        let height = element.offsetHeight;
        let lines = height / lineHeight;
        return Math.round(lines);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setItems(window.location.pathname.split("/").filter((e) => e.length > 0))
    }, [window.location.pathname])

    useEffect(() => {
        const lines = countLines(wrapper.current, ellipsis.current.clientHeight);
        const maxLines = 2;

        if (lines > maxLines) {
            setItems(items.slice(1));
            setDropped(true);
        }
    }, [items])

    return <nav className="breadcrumbs-wrapper" ref={wrapper}>
        <span ref={ellipsis}>
            {dropped ? "..." : ""}
        </span>
        {items.map((item, index) => {
            return <span key={index.toString()}>
                <span>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="#">{item}</a>
            </span>
        })}
    </nav>
}

export default Breadcrumbs;
```

Breadcrumbs.css

```
.breadcrumbs-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Here are screenshots of the working example

[image: One line without wrappings]

[image: Two lines]

[image: More than two lines]

Comment: What happens if the path is length like "This is a path example" ?

Answer (score 0):

import React from 'react';
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

```
const Breadcrumb = ({ handleDrawerOpen, open }) => {
   const { pathname } = useLocation();

   const pathName = (paths, index) => {
      return paths.filter((path, pathIndex) => pathIndex !== 0 && pathIndex <= index).join('/');
   };
   
   const func = () => {
      const paths = pathname.split('/');
      return paths.map(
         (path, index) =>
            index !== 0 && (
               <Link
                  style={{
                     textDecoration: 'none',
                     color: index === paths.length - 1 ? '#49C5B6' : 'white',
                  }}
                  to={`/${pathName(paths, index)}`}>{`${
                  path?.charAt(0)?.toUpperCase() + path.slice(1).toLowerCase()
               } ${index !== paths.length - 1 ? '>' : ''} `}</Link>
            )
      );
   };
   return (
      <Box>
         {!open && (
            <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerOpen}>
               <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
         )}

         <Profile />
      </Box>
   );
};

export default Breadcrumb;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice last 5 items and map through them to render the links:

```
breadcrumbs.slice(-5).map((breadcrumb, index) => (
<React.Fragment key={index}>
  {index !== 0 && breadcrumbs.length > 1 ? ' / ' : ''}
  {index === 0 && breadcrumb.path !== breadcrumbs[0].path ? (
    '...'
  ) : (
    <a href={breadcrumb.link}>{breadcrumb.path}</a>
  )}
  {index % 2 ? <br /> : ''}
</React.Fragment>
```

Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-eqtnrh?file=App.tsx) representing your requirement.